# CSS scale triggered by mouseover or onclick?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some CSS that scales images, which works fine.

The problem is it gets applied to every image on the page. What I want is to apply it ONLY to an image if I mouseover or onclick.

Because images are inserted by a CMS used by non-tech writers, they don't have the skills to get into the image tag itself to insert a class. This is why I want the scaling CSS triggered by mouseover or onclick.

I've struggled to get a piece of javascript to do the job and would appreciate some help

Comment: Are you trying to extend the cms editor to let non technical editors apply the css scaling to images they insert?

Comment: have you tried the `:hover` css pseudo-selector?

Comment: fine can you show some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just bind the event to the tag and use `this`:

```
   var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
   for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
        images[i].onmouseover = imgScale;
        images[i].onclick = imgScale;
   }
   function imgScale(e) {
       this.style.width = 500px; //whatever
       this.setAttribute("class", "image-scale");
   }
```

If jQuery:

```
$('img').on('hover click', function() { 
       $(this).css('width','500px');
       $(this).addClass('image-scale');
});
```

Even better, if you only need on hover you can use just CSS:

```
img:hover {
   width: 500px;
}
```

You could try using

```
img:active
```

To detect a click, but I believe it will only make changes while the mouse is pressed down, as soon as they let up it is no longer `:active`

Comment: A perfect solution. I didn't know about image:hover despite reading everything I could find beforehand and this technique does exactly what we want.

Comment: If you want to switch between images when you click, you can use `img:focus` @StefanYoungs

Answer (score 1):

You may try using CSS 3 for scaling. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/772V5/2/).

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms 0ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms 0ms ease-in-out;
    width: 50px;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for taking the trouble to respond. I appreciate it. img:hover did the trick